# Is it possible to sign a message with a base58 secret key with Tweetnacl library?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, key, signature, nacl-cryptography

I've generated a key pair using [Tweetnacl.js](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js):

```
const base58KeyPairGenerator = (seed: Uint8Array) => ({
    publicKey: keyToPublicIdentityKey(nacl.sign.keyPair.fromSeed(seed).publicKey),
    secretKey: seedToSecretIdentityKey(seed)
});

const keyToPublicIdentityKey = (key) => {
    return keyToIdentityKey(key, 'idpub');
};

const seedToSecretIdentityKey = (seed) => {
    return keyToIdentityKey(seed, 'idsec');
};

const keyToIdentityKey = (key, prefix) => {
    const keyBuffer = Buffer.from(key, 'hex');
    if (keyBuffer.length !== 32) {
        throw new Error('Key/seed must be 32 bytes long.');
    }
    const address = Buffer.concat([prefix, keyBuffer]);
    const checksum = sha256d(address).slice(0, 4);
    return base58.encode(Buffer.concat([address, checksum]));
};

const sha256d = (data) => {
    return Buffer.from(
        sha256()
            .update(
                sha256()
                    .update(data)
                    .digest()
            )
            .digest()
    );
};

const keyPair = base58KeyPairGenerator(nacl.randomBytes(32));
```

Now that I have a base58 key pair (public key and secret key in base58), I want to sign a message with the secret key like this:

```
nacl.sign(
          Buffer.from(someStringMessage, 'hex'),
          base58.decode(keyPair.secretKey)
        )
```

`base58` here is from [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-58) library.

However I get this error:

```
bad secret key size

      at Object.<anonymous>.nacl.sign (node_modules/tweetnacl/nacl-fast.js:2257:11)
```

Indeed, the `nacl.sign` function expects a 64bits secret key and that's not the case of my base58 version.

Is there a way to fix it while keeping base58 or should I use the original Ed25519 format generated by `nacl.randomBytes(32)`, meaning the not- transformed one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That being said, NaCl signing keys are 64 bytes, not 32. Hence the error you get.

In the `base58KeyPairGenerator` function, the secret key must be the output of `nacl.sign.keyPair.fromSeed(seed).secretKey` (or `.privateKey` or whatever it's called), not just the seed.